# Flutter Web Compile Failed

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I am trying to 'flutter build web' but it keep exiting abnormally. I am using Android Studio.

main.dart starting

```
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/utils/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/auth/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/dashboard/dashboard_screen.dart';
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/server/add_server_screen.dart';
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/server/edit_server_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/routes/get_route.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/routes/transitions_type.dart';
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';
import 'di_container.dart' as di;
```

pubspec.yaml dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^4.0.6
  advanced_navigator: ^1.0.1
  lottie: ^2.6.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
  get: ^4.6.6
  get_it: ^7.6.4
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0
  file_picker: ^5.5.0
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
```

Error

```
Target dart2js failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/utils/app_constants.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/auth/login_screen.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/dashboard/dashboard_screen.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/server/add_server_screen.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/server/edit_server_screen.dart'.
lib/main.dart:1:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/utils/app_constants.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/utils/app_constants.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:2:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/auth/login_screen.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/auth/login_screen.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:3:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/dashboard/dashboard_screen.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/dashboard/dashboard_screen.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:4:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/server/add_server_screen.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/server/add_server_screen.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:5:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/server/edit_server_screen.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/view/screens/server/edit_server_screen.dart';
       ^
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/add_server_controller.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/auth_controller.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/server_delete_controller.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/update_admin_profile_controller.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/add_server_repo.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/server_update_repo.dart'.
lib/di_container.dart:8:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/utils/app_constants.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/utils/app_constants.dart';
       ^
lib/di_container.dart:2:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/add_server_controller.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/add_server_controller.dart';
       ^
lib/di_container.dart:3:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/auth_controller.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/auth_controller.dart';
       ^
lib/di_container.dart:4:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/server_delete_controller.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/server_delete_controller.dart';
       ^
lib/di_container.dart:5:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/update_admin_profile_controller.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/controllers/update_admin_profile_controller.dart';
       ^
lib/di_container.dart:6:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/add_server_repo.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/add_server_repo.dart';
       ^
lib/di_container.dart:7:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/server_update_repo.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/server_update_repo.dart';
       ^
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/admin_profile_repo.dart'.
lib/controllers/edit_server_controller.dart:1:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/server_update_repo.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/server_update_repo.dart';
       ^
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/server_details_repo.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel' in 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/view_all_server_repo.dart'.
lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart:2:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/utils/app_constants.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/utils/app_constants.dart';
       ^
lib/controllers/admin_profile_controller.dart:2:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/admin_profile_repo.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/admin_profile_repo.dart';
       ^
lib/controllers/server_details_controller.dart:2:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/server_details_repo.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/server_details_repo.dart';
       ^
lib/controllers/view_all_server_controller.dart:1:8:
Error: Not found: 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/view_all_server_repo.dart'
import 'package:eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel/data/repository/view_all_server_repo.dart';
       ^
lib/controllers/admin_profile_controller.dart:12:9:
Error: Type 'AdminProfileRepo' not found.
  final AdminProfileRepo adminProfileRepo;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/controllers/edit_server_controller.dart:17:9:
Error: Type 'ServerUpdateRepo' not found.
  final ServerUpdateRepo serverUpdateRepo;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/controllers/server_details_controller.dart:12:9:
Error: Type 'ServerDetailsRepo' not found.
  final ServerDetailsRepo serverDetailsRepo;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/controllers/view_all_server_controller.dart:10:9:
Error: Type 'ViewAllServerRepo' not found.
  final ViewAllServerRepo viewAllServerRepo;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:28:14:
Error: The getter 'AppConstants' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
      title: AppConstants.appName,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:33:21:
Error: The getter 'LoginScreen' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
      initialRoute: LoginScreen.routeName,
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:35:23:
Error: The getter 'LoginScreen' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
        GetPage(name: LoginScreen.routeName, page: () => LoginScreen()),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:35:58:
Error: The method 'LoginScreen' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
        GetPage(name: LoginScreen.routeName, page: () => LoginScreen()),
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:36:23:
Error: The getter 'DashboardScreen' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
        GetPage(name: DashboardScreen.routeName, page: () => DashboardScreen(), transition: Transition.fadeIn, transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:36:62:
Error: The method 'DashboardScreen' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
        GetPage(name: DashboardScreen.routeName, page: () => DashboardScreen(), transition: Transition.fadeIn, transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:37:23:
Error: The getter 'CreateServerScreen' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
        GetPage(name: CreateServerScreen.routeName, page: () => CreateServerScreen(), transition: Transition.fadeIn, transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:37:65:
Error: The method 'CreateServerScreen' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
        GetPage(name: CreateServerScreen.routeName, page: () => CreateServerScreen(), transition: Transition.fadeIn, transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:38:23:
Error: The getter 'EditServerScreen' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
        GetPage(name: EditServerScreen.routeName, page: () => EditServerScreen(), transition: Transition.fadeIn, transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:38:63:
Error: The method 'EditServerScreen' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
        GetPage(name: EditServerScreen.routeName, page: () => EditServerScreen(), transition: Transition.fadeIn, transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/di_container.dart:31:44:
Error: Undefined name 'AppConstants'.
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => DioClient(AppConstants.baseUrl, sl(), loggingInterceptor: sl(), sharedPreferences: sl()));
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/di_container.dart:35:34:
Error: Method not found: 'AddServerRepo'.
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => AddServerRepo(dioClient: sl(), sharedPreferences: sl()));
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/di_container.dart:40:34:
Error: Method not found: 'ServerUpdateRepo'.
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => ServerUpdateRepo(dioClient: sl(), sharedPreferences: sl()));
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/di_container.dart:45:21:
Error: Method not found: 'AuthController'.
  Get.lazyPut(() => AuthController(dioClient: sl(), authRepo: sl()), fenix: true);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/di_container.dart:46:21:
Error: Method not found: 'AddServerController'.
  Get.lazyPut(() => AddServerController(dioClient: sl(), addServerRepo: sl()), fenix: true);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/di_container.dart:49:21:
Error: Method not found: 'ServerDeleteController'.
  Get.lazyPut(() => ServerDeleteController(dioClient: sl(), serverDeleteRepo: sl()), fenix: true);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/di_container.dart:50:21:
Error: Method not found: 'UpdateAdminProfileController'.
  Get.lazyPut(() => UpdateAdminProfileController(dioClient: sl(), updateAdminProfileRepo: sl()), fenix: true);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/controllers/admin_profile_controller.dart:12:9:
Error: 'AdminProfileRepo' isn't a type.
  final AdminProfileRepo adminProfileRepo;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/controllers/edit_server_controller.dart:17:9:
Error: 'ServerUpdateRepo' isn't a type.
  final ServerUpdateRepo serverUpdateRepo;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/controllers/server_details_controller.dart:12:9:
Error: 'ServerDetailsRepo' isn't a type.
  final ServerDetailsRepo serverDetailsRepo;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/controllers/view_all_server_controller.dart:10:9:
Error: 'ViewAllServerRepo' isn't a type.
  final ViewAllServerRepo viewAllServerRepo;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart:20:9:
Error: The getter 'AppConstants' isn't defined for the class 'AuthRepo'.
 - 'AuthRepo' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/data/repository/auth_repo.dart' ('lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart').
        AppConstants.loginUrl,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart:36:41:
Error: The getter 'AppConstants' isn't defined for the class 'AuthRepo'.
 - 'AuthRepo' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/data/repository/auth_repo.dart' ('lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart').
      await sharedPreferences.setString(AppConstants.token, token);
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart:38:47:
Error: The getter 'AppConstants' isn't defined for the class 'AuthRepo'.
 - 'AuthRepo' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/data/repository/auth_repo.dart' ('lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart').
      print(await sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.token));
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart:47:56:
Error: The getter 'AppConstants' isn't defined for the class 'AuthRepo'.
 - 'AuthRepo' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/data/repository/auth_repo.dart' ('lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart').
    dioClient.updateHeader(sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.token) ?? "", "");
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart:48:40:
Error: The getter 'AppConstants' isn't defined for the class 'AuthRepo'.
 - 'AuthRepo' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/data/repository/auth_repo.dart' ('lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart').
    return sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.token) ?? "";
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart:54:37:
Error: The getter 'AppConstants' isn't defined for the class 'AuthRepo'.
 - 'AuthRepo' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/data/repository/auth_repo.dart' ('lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart').
    return sharedPreferences.remove(AppConstants.token);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart:65:41:
Error: The getter 'AppConstants' isn't defined for the class 'AuthRepo'.
 - 'AuthRepo' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/data/repository/auth_repo.dart' ('lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart').
      await sharedPreferences.setString(AppConstants.token, token);
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart:73:40:
Error: The getter 'AppConstants' isn't defined for the class 'AuthRepo'.
 - 'AuthRepo' is from 'package:remote_ip_vpn_admin_panel/data/repository/auth_repo.dart' ('lib/data/repository/auth_repo.dart').
    return sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.token) ?? "";
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
  Command: C:\dev\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\dev\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\dart2js.dart.snapshot
  --platform-binaries=C:\dev\flutter\bin\cache\flutter_web_sdk\kernel --invoker=flutter_tool -Ddart.vm.product=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true
  -DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/0545f8705df301877d787107bac1a6e9fc9ee1ad/ --native-null-assertions --no-source-maps -o
  C:\Users\brije\Downloads\EYE_VPN_LITE_SOURCE_CODE\EYE_VPN_LITE_SOURCE_CODE\eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel\.dart_tool\flutter_build\06edd3d07f0b028e0af881e89663c234\app.dill
  --packages=.dart_tool/package_config.json --cfe-only
  C:\Users\brije\Downloads\EYE_VPN_LITE_SOURCE_CODE\EYE_VPN_LITE_SOURCE_CODE\eye_vpn_lite_admin_panel\.dart_tool\flutter_build\06edd3d07f0b028e0af881e89663c234\main.dart
#0      RunResult.throwException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:125:5)
#1      _DefaultProcessUtils.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:278:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Dart2JSTarget.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/web.dart:189:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:853:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:525:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:791:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:525:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:791:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:620:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      WebBuilder.buildWeb (package:flutter_tools/src/web/compile.dart:89:34)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     BuildWebCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_web.dart:198:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1297:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:339:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:285:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:115:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
<asynchronous suspension>

Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...                             27.9s
Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
```

I'm getting error even after following all the troubleshooting guides.

Quit and reopened Android Studio
Cross checked if my lib folder has all the packages I am trying to import
Ran `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`. `flutter pub cache clean`.

I don't know if it is the problem with the Android Studio itself.

Tried using flutter's dart-sdk and custom dart-sdk both, thought maybe there was any problem with the dart-sdk, but still the same.

I tried this on both Mac and Windows 10, still the same thing.

Comment: Try updating with the Flutter version maybe it will help.

Comment: @ShabbirRajput I fresh installed the Flutter just before this project. I ran flutter upgrade, and it was the latest version.